# PWA - Add to Home Screen Prompt on iOS?

Tags: jquery, ios, mobile, progressive-web-apps

I know iOS doesn't support the native 'Add to Home Screen' prompt for PWA's like android does, however what is a work around to prompt the user to shortcut the PWA?

I've looked everywhere for an example, even a simple modal window with instructions on how to save the PWA to their phone, but haven't had success in finding a viable solution.

edit:
I tried this solution, but it did not work on iPhone.
https://github.com/cubiq/add-to-homescreen

Answer (score 1):

I forked Matias' repo last year and updated it.
https://love2dev.com/pwa/add-to-homescreen-library/
As for examples of how to prompt the user that is up to you as to how you want to do that. I like to 'guide the user', especially on iOS to the Add to Homescreen steps.
I also made a tool, https://pwastarter.love2dev.com/ that will help scaffold out your PWA assets and create a large set of homescreen icons.

I am always looking for feedback on the library and PWA Starter!

Comment: Does the tool also provide a solution for iOS add to home screen?

Comment: Yes, it generates the META tags to reference the touch icons. But I will say, iOS Safari seems to now be using the icons referenced in the web manifest file these days.
I suspect touch icons will head for deprecation in the next couple of years.